# Код выдает ошибку 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Код:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

   i = 1
while True:
    i = +1
    if i > 2000:
        break

    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.moveTo(975, 361)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    keyboard.write(i)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1037, 756)
```

Comment: Примите ответ если он вам помог (галочка около ответа)

Comment: исправил, так работает ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
counter = 1
while True:
    counter += 1
    if counter > 2000:
        break

    time.sleep(10)
    pyautogui.moveTo(975, 361)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    keyboard.write(str(counter))
    time.sleep(0.3)
    pyautogui.moveTo(1037, 756)
```

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/trade bot/bot/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    keyboard.write(counter)
  File "C:\Users\Krater\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 844, in write
    for letter in text:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Думаю тут нужно строку писать, а не `int`: `keyboard.write(str(counter))`

Comment: @finally Зря ругаете автора вопроса — просто начинающий.

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Comment: @finally VictorsaysReinstateMonica абсолютно прав! Вы тоже когда-то были начинающим. Задача СО помочь, а не гнобить тех, кто задаёт вопросы.

Comment: @Denis640Kb тем более что вопрос задан вполне нормально

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не вполне. В "нормально заданном" вопросе  присутствует полный текст ошибки и строка, на которой эта ошибка происходит.

Comment: @Эникейщик Хорошее уточнение , хотя главное в ошибке — последняя строчка.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Как видно из истории правок вашего ответа - одной последней строчки совершенно недостаточно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну это да :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica "Он недружелюбен или враждебен" ?? я лишь указал, что лeзть туда, куда нe понимаeшь - нe лучшая затeя. Я ж нe запрeщаю никому учиться, но такиe вот, которыe только сeли и ужe подавай всe на блюдцe всe только портят

Comment: @finally Тем не менее не стоит так писать. Модераторы сочли это за "Он недружелюбен или враждебен". Хотя лично у всех свое мнение :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica вот имeнно, что у всeх всe своe, что там творится в умах модeрации мнe, простому смeртному, познать нe дано, но оскорблeний тот комeнтарий нe нeс, раз уж кто то сюда обращаeтся, он должeн быть готов к АДeКВАТНОЙ критикe

Comment: @finally Справедливая критика должна быть высказана без перехода на личности. А модераторы не зря носят ромбы, они должны поддерживать относительную доброжелательность.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica думайтe как хотитe, я нe считаю, что должна царить "дружeствeнная" атмосфeра, нeйтральной вполнe хватит, но спорить нe буду, а то в мою то чeсть ники никто мeнять нe станeт..

Comment: @finally Да ладно, в принципе вполне нормальный комметарий был. Просто участник новый, не стоит отпугивать. **P.S** "...says Reinsate Finally" a что звучит... :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102838/discussion-between-finally-and-victor-says-reinstate-monica).